# Injecting JOOQ Context using CDI and JNDI

Tags: java, jsf, wildfly, cdi, jooq

I try to use jooq on an PostgreSQL Database. The Web-App is built on the JSF Framework using CDI for dependency injection. The server is WildFly 11.

I use the jooq codegen to generate pojos and daos.

Following the instructions on http://awolski.com/integrating-jooq-easy/
I should be able to inject the DSLContext into any class. When I try to inject it into a controller bean which looks like

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class FooView implements Serializable {

    private @Inject DSLContext jooq;
...
```

it simply doesn't work. The framework just doesn't instantiate the Foo.

What am I missing?

The server.log reads as follows:

```
WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (Weld Thread Pool -- 4) Failed to define class model.tables.FooDao in Module "deployment.project.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link model/tables/Foo (Module "deployment.project.war" from Service Module Loader): org/jooq/impl/TableImpl
...
INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "project.war" (runtime-name : "project.war")
...
WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-22) /project/Foo.xhtml @9,91 value="#{FooView.attr}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'FooView' resolved to null: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /project/Foo.xhtml @9,91 value="#{FooView.attr}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'FooView' resolved to null
...
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'FooView' resolved to null
...
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-22) UT005023: Exception handling request to /project/project/Foo.xhtml: javax.servlet.ServletException: /project/Foo.xhtml @9,91 value="#{FooView.attr}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'FooView' resolved to null
...
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /project/Foo.xhtml @9,91 value="#{FooView.attr}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'FooView' resolved to null
...
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'FooView' resolved to null
```

As soon as I remove the injected attribute from FooView, no errors show up, despite that warning.

Comment: Is the jar for jooq in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your war? The first WARN of the server.log shows that the needed class `org/jooq/impl/TableImpl` is missing.

Comment: Oh yes, I messed up the packaging. Changed stucture to maven standard and used the right packaging target. Now it works :-)